# для сокетов типа af_unix (unix:\tmp\my_socket) как узнать что файл соответствует слушающему сокету?

Tags: c++, linux, unix-socket

после работы с af_unix сокетом на команду bind создается файл, который по завершении работы с сокетом необходимо удалить unlink, но если работа завершилась не корректно то файл остается - как проверить, что файл не привязан к unix сокету и его нужно удалить перед bind-ом?
Коннектиться и влиять на работу другого приложения не хотелось бы.

Comment: Если этого файла нет в выводе команды `netstat -a` (т.е. `netstat -a | grep your-FILE ||  rm your-FILE`) (но если у вас, судя по бэкслешам в заголовке, все же винда, то я не уверен, что конвейер в примере сработает)

Comment: конечно unix:/tmp/my_socket - на linux, а не внешней программой а в коде на с++? netstat работает, но ее еще и отдельно ставить надо.

Comment: можно посмотреть в /proc/net/unix

Comment: Ни разу не видел linux где изначально нет netstat-а. Из c/с++ запустить проще всего через `system()`